# Create jquery event for entire body for click event

Tags: jquery, css

Here I have created Dropdown list. When click on edit box it displays menu item.

When I select menu item, after that it menu popup gets closed.

But once popup items are opened and If I click outside popup box it should close the item. 
How can I do it?

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/F78Ng/)

JS:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'Some name',
    local: ['Sports', 'Entertainment', 'Politics', 'Technolohy', 'Technolohy Again']
})
$('.typeahead.input-sm').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-small');
$('.typeahead.input-lg').siblings('input.tt-hint').addClass('hint-large');

$(".typeahead").click(function () {
    var defaultval = $(".typeahead").val();
    $('.dropdown-menu').show(1200);
});


$('ul.dropdown-menu >li').on('click', function(){
    var idd = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = ($("#"+idd).text());
    alert(val);
    $(".typeahead").val(val);
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').hide(600);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the blur event:

```
$(".typeahead").on('blur', function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide(1200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RZTu5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a click function to the document to hide the popup, but assign a click function to the popup to prevent that.

```
var $popup = $('.the-popup');

$(document).click(function() {
    $popup.hide();
});
$popup.click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eGIgINo/2/edit)**

In your case, this logic would look like:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').hide(600);
});
$('.typeahead').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

For what you're doing the `blur` event is also useful, since it will fire a function when the input loses focus (when you click somewhere else). The behavior is the same either way. The difference here is that `blur` is a bit more restricted. If the popup were shown by something other than the input (the input doesn't have focus) clicking elsewhere wouldn't hide it. Either way works in your case. For completeness, here is a generic example of that:

```
var $popup = $('.the-popup');
var $input = $('.my-input');

$input.focus(function() {
  $popup.show();
});
$input.blur(function() {
  $popup.hide();
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eGIgINo/3/edit)**